# Magento 2: what does i18n mean?

Tags: magento2, localisation

When I started working with Magento 2, that was the first time I came accross this abbreviation so I have no idea **what does that word/abbreviation mean** ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wikipedia answered my question:

> ### Internationalization and localization
>
> The terms are frequently abbreviated to the numeronyms **i18n** (where
>   18 stands for the number of letters between the first i and the last n
>   in the word internationalization, a usage coined at DEC in the 1970s
>   or 80s)[3][4] and **L10n** for localization, due to the length of the
>   words.

So if you ever wonder **i18n** means **internationalization**

Comment: it's also because developers are both lazy and code is prone to typos. i18n is *much* shorter to type and easier to verify correct spelling than `internationalization`. Especially before the days of spell check. There are quite a few other abbreviations like this when you have a really long word that nobody wants to type. `_` is also occasionally used for internationalization as a shorthand.

Comment: Note that internationalization and localization are distinct concepts (although i18n is often used to refer to both). l10n is also used to refer to localization.

Answer (score 4):

i18n folder will use for translate content for multi language.

For eg. website have multiple language option so need translation for all content. and translation will put inside i18n folder in as CSV format.

> eg. vendor\magento\module-cms\i18n\en_US.csv

```
"Save and Continue Edit","Save and Continue Edit"
```

change to `"Save and Continue Edit","Save and Edit Again"` and test

For translated content use like in frontend as `__("Save and Continue Edit")`

Comment: I was not asking for the purpose of the i18n folder, I was asking for the meaning of the word i18n (see my answer)